# QT DockWidgetArea customization

Tags: c++, qt

I am curious if anyone can help at least point me in the right direction, as I am still a novice with QT and only somewhat more knowledgable with cpp. I have the `Qt::TopDockWidgetArea` set across the entire *QMainWindow* instance, as I want it to be. In the `Qt::LeftDockWidgetArea`, however, I do not want the dock area to extend completely vertically down beyond the instance of the *QDockWidget* (that I was able to set a size constraint on), and it is occupying far too much real estate on the underlying window/centralWidget area (which is a viewport). I would also like to get rid of some of the separator icons between dock area items...

Thank-you in advance to anyone who might be able to offer a little advice. Oh, I also am not integrating the Qt Designer into this, so this presentation layer is being "hard-coded".

Comment: From the documentation it looks like you have to control this in the children rather than in the DockWidget : "A QDockWidget acts as a wrapper for its child widget, set with setWidget(). Custom size hints, minimum and maximum sizes and size policies should be implemented in the child widget. QDockWidget will respect them, adjusting its own constraints to include the frame and title. Size constraints should not be set on the QDockWidget itself, because they change depending on whether it is docked; a docked QDockWidget has no frame and a smaller title bar."

Comment: That is all true, however its not the QDockWidget instance I am having issues with, but more to do with QMainWindow's layout management regarding its "dock widget areas". The layout manager has a container (retractable), that I would rather not be visible beyond the QDockWidget instance itself.

Comment: I see, then you need to show some code/structure. It is difficult to see all that from the text.

Comment: Im just not really sure what code to even show, I think this may be a default attribute which I am just not certain how to access.... I thought maybe DockWidgetArea_Mask would do something, but I cannot find any reference describing what it actually does or how to use it, maybe it is deprecated?

Comment: I dont think the mask can do something with sizes.

Comment: That's likely the case, but it could allow for transparency of the widget area.